# Permanently edit webpages?

Tags: live, edit, html, permanent

Is it possible to edit a webpage and make the changes permanent? (on my machine of course)
So, for example, if a webpage wasn't displaying properly could I edit the html code and save the changes. Everytime I revisit the site, the changes are there.

I was using greasemonkey but it would be preferable if I could edit the html directly.

Thanks.

Comment: What if the HTML is dynamic, like with most sites you visit?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic? I could change the html with firebug or something similar but the change would not be persistent.

Comment: He means if the HTML changes over time, or from page load to page load.  Like the HTML for the page you are viewing has changed to include this comment I just wrote.

Comment: No, he wants to get things right in Firebug or similar and then save those changes without having to go back to the source and reimplement all the tweaks done in Firebug -- export the changeset back to the source. It would be nice.

Comment: ^Jay -That is what I am looking for.